# Why I can't remove this Eclipse plugin after failed installation?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, flash-builder

I am using **Eclipse Mars** and I have the following problem.

After the installation of a plugin, the **Adoe Flash Builder** plugin, it is a plugin that is installed outside Eclipse (executing an installer and selecting the Eclipse folder) I have some problem.

The plugin installation failed (because this plugin is supported only on the 32 bit version of Eclipse). So the plugin was not completly installed.

When I start Eclipse I obtain a lot of error messages caused by this failed installation and it is impossible to me work.

So I have tried to disinstall this plugin but it doesn't give me the possibility to uninstall it (the **Uninstall** button is disabled).

Here the screenshot where you can see that, selecting the plugin that I want to uninstall, the **Uninstall** button is disabled:

[image]

Why? Can I manually delete this plugin in some way? (I have not directory related to it into my Eclipse folder). It seems that in some way Eclipse have the information of this plugin but that this is not effectively present. How can I remove it? Or is faster reinstall and configure again my environment (Eclipse + SVN plugin + project configuration)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried sometimes to get rid of "messed up" eclipse configurations.

In the end, it just didn't work out. I always ended up throwing away everything.

Besides: Eclipse Neon R2a was released already; so just download that and say goodbye to Mars.

And the real answer (in my opinionated eyes): I decided at some point to enable myself to install eclipse "from scratch" as quickly as possible (for example by having automation where possible; and "checklists" to follow where manual interaction is required). Simply because "installing from scratch" helps avoiding a lot of problems over time.

And while we are talking about eclipse best practices: *if* your OS is Linux, consider to switch to git-svn instead of SVN. Your machine still talks SVN to the remote SVN server, but you can enjoy the full beauty of git locally. No more SVN plugins, no more hours of waiting for that SVN plugin doing refresh ... I can't tell you how much time that simply change saved for me.